# How to show all days regardless of activity

Tags: mysql, date

I have two tables - quotes and bookings

I am selecting "quote date" to show the day of the week but if a booking is made on a day without a quote, then there is no "quote date" and therefore this row is never displayed.

How can I created a column that is just every day for the past 30,60 or 90 days then shows the number of quotes for that given day and the number of bookings?

Current SQL Using QuoteDate:

```
SELECT 
  cast(q.created as date) AS QuoteDate,
  count(q.id) AS Quotes,
  count(b.quote_id) AS Bookings
FROM quotes q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bookings b ON b.quote_id=q.id
WHERE year(q.created)='2010'
AND month(q.created)='09'
GROUP BY cast(q.created as date)
ORDER BY cast(q.created as date) DESC
```

These results will not display bookings on days where no quotes were made...